# Xcode (iOS) sigabrt Error 'Could not load NIB in bundle

Tags: xcode

I have a ver hard time with Xcode in my app project, I built a memory game and it's includes levels, the game is working perfect till level 10 and after that I got this crash error, when I try to delete level 10 the game is working perfect but when I play again the game is crash in level 2 ! ( it's mean the Xcode can't run the app project for more than 9 or 10 levels then it will be crash) ..

this is my code :

```
-(void)delay2 {    
    level3  *second = [[level3 alloc] initWithNibName:@"level3" bundle:nil];

    [self presentModalViewController:second animated:YES];    
}
```

Here the crash report :

> **Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle  (loaded)' with name 'level3''
>   ** First throw call stack: **

I am using Xcode 4.1

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have an **.XIB** file named **level3** in your project. Also make sure that the TargetMembership is checked for this XIB so that it will be compiled when building.

Comment: I checked all XIB Files and it's TargetMembership checked, and I have file named level3.XIB . the crash is not always in that file .. some times in the another file .. it looks like the time I use the app and play the game .. it's suddenly crash after I switch view between around 8 or 10 files . Also when I try to go directly to each file even level3 file it's working perfect .. but the problem is coming after I use the app and switch between files (levels) . I tried many steps but the problem isn't solved . the crash is in the both devise and the simulator. ..

Comment: The error you provided suggests that the file doesn't exist, double check your project again.

Comment: the file is exist .. and I will explain more .. my app is memory matching game, it's from 10 levels .. when I start the game it's working perfect from level 1,2,3,4 .. till 10 and I play again it's working fine but then it's crash in level 2 or level 3 .. i tried  all answers here and in the google but I still got the error .. I submit the app to the iTunes and I am worry about that ..

Comment: Does your app use ARC? If not, then you are probably using up too many resources.

Comment: Yes my app use arc , what can I do for that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the xib to your project build phase [this link will be hlpfull](http://codefriends.blogspot.in/2012/04/hi-i-faced-this-problem-and-want-to.html)

go to build phases and add the xib.

Comment: I check the link you gave me and follow the steps and they said in build phases,,,,,,,(3.Click + symbol and a finder will open  if you see any .m file in it select it and when all .m files are selected click on add button)... ,,,,,,,,, but  i didn't see any file.m in that step ! it's really hard problem .

Comment: To add xib you need to go to build phases and open copy bundle resources tab..rest is same like adding .m file

Comment: You didnt see any .m files because they are already linked.Cmnt if your problem is solved

Comment: I Need to add file.m only or file.h + file.m ? from copy bundle resources ?

Comment: I checked and I saw all XIB files are added to build phases and still I got the crash ..

Comment: buddy i think it will be tough without code try putting breakpoint at dealloc to see if dealloc of class is getting called before its call